# Проблема Gulp сборки: при компиляции кастомного Bootstrap (sass), обновленная страница не содержит сделанных изменений

Tags: bootstrap, gulp, bower

Моя логика: Использую  Gulp - Bower - Bootstrap. 
Я компилирую бутстрап из sass файла с измененными переменными в bootstrap-custom.css, указываю этот файл в bower.json - main. Вставляю ссылку на него в html с помощью wiredep, потом объединяю библиотеки в vendor.css с помощью useref и отправляю всё в build.

При изменении каких-либо переменных в bootstrap-user-custom нужно снова скомпилировать новый bootstrap-custom, и снова собрать html. Проблема в том, что в моём случае в файл с вновь скомпилированный бутстрапом мои изменения попадают, а в сборку нет, только со второго прохода. Ставил зависимость таска html:build от boot:compile - ничего. Пробовал вручную указать таймаут для html:build - получается, но только не на Live сервере. Сломал голову, не понимаю что пропустил, буду очень благодарен помощи!

Код gulpfile.js и index.html в части касающейся проблемы прилагаю

```js
var path = {
  build: {
    //Адреса куда ложить файлы сборки
    html: 'build/',
    js: 'build/js/',
    css: 'build/css/',
    img: 'build/img/',
    fonts: 'build/fonts/'
  },
  src: {
    //Откуда брать исходники
    html: 'src/*.html',
    js: 'src/js/main.js',
    css: 'src/style/main.styl',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
  },
  watch: {
    //За изменениями каких файлов мы хотим наблюдать
    html: 'src/**/*.html',
    js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
    css: 'src/style/**/*.styl',
    scss: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
    img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
  },
  clean: './build',
  bootstrap: {
    src: 'bower_components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-custom.scss',
    dist: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css'
  }
};

var config = {
  server: {
    baseDir: "./build"
  },
  tunnel: true,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 9000,
  logPrefix: "laplandin"
}; //Настройки нашего live-сервера

gulp.task('boot:compile', () => {
    gulp.src(path.bootstrap.src)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.bootstrap.dist));
});

gulp.task('html:build', ['boot:compile'], function() {
    //setTimeout(function() {
      gulp.src(path.src.html) //выбор фалов по нужному пути
      .pipe(rigger()) //вставляет код файла вместо указанного к файлу пути
      .pipe(wiredep()) // устанавливает ссылки на зависимости bower и вставляет их в проект
      .pipe(useref()) // собирает сторонние библиотеки в vendor файл
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)) //папка назначения
      .pipe(reload({stream:true})); //Перезагрузка сервера
    //}, 1000)
});

gulp.task('build', [
  'html:build',
  'js:build',
  'css:build',
  'fonts:build',
  'image:build'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch([path.watch.scss], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('html:build');
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- build:css css/vendor.css -->
        <!-- bower:css -->
        <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="site-wrapper container">
        //= template/nav.html
        //= template/header.html
        //= template/footer.html
    </div>

    //= template/article-item-template.html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

понимаю что вопросу много времени, но оставлю тут решение для других

```
gulp.task('boot:compile', () => {
    gulp.src(path.bootstrap.src)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.bootstrap.dist))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true})); //Перезагрузка сервера  <- тут добавляем строку
});

gulp.task('html:watch', ['html:build'], (done) => {
    reload();
    done();
});

gulp.task('html:build', function() { // <- убираем из зависимостей boot:compile
      gulp.src(path.src.html) //выбор фалов по нужному пути
      .pipe(rigger()) //вставляет код файла вместо указанного к файлу пути
      .pipe(wiredep()) // устанавливает ссылки на зависимости bower и вставляет их в проект
      .pipe(useref()) // собирает сторонние библиотеки в vendor файл
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)); //папка назначения 
      // <- тут убираем reload
});

// новая задача для html
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, {cwd: './'}, ['html:watch']); // <- немного поменяли watch'ер 
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

P.S. Не проверял, возможны опечатки и как следствие не рабочий конфиг, но думаю суть ясна, можно также об этом посмотреть на официальном сайте browser sync в документации